# Select across pages in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to visual select multiple pages in Vim?

When I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to enter selection mode, the keys <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> work to select more text, but page up and page down <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> exit out of the "select" mode.

FYI I am using GVIM on Windows 7.

Comment: Odd, ctrl-n and ctrl-p don't exit visual mode for me.

Comment: @Kevin, they will if you have `behave mswin` enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

- use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>, which keeps a selection under mswin and moves half a page
- put `behave xterm` into your vimrc file, which makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> work as well
- use searching with <kbd>/</kbd> as described in post of Zsolt

Comment: [`:behave xterm`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui.txt.html#%3Abehave) makes changes to the values of multiple options. The pertinent one here seems to be the removal of `stopsel` from [`keymodel`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27keymodel%27). While this does let CTRL-F and CTRL-B adjust an active visual selection, it also prevents other non-shifted cursor movement (i.e. Shift-Up/Down/Left/Right/PageUp/PageDown, etc.) from canceling the active selection; this may be confusing for a user that expects the “usual” GUI-based selection handling.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, you can use <kbd>/</kbd> to search for something after <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> and your lines will be selected till (and including) the next match.

It can be better, as you sometimes don't know what's on the next page.